How to display backend configuration using Terraform CLI?
I often find myself forgetting which remote state I'm operating on.
I can query the list of workspaces using terraform workspaces list, but I've several remote states with similar workspaces, so the list of workspaces doesn't necessarily uniquely identify the remote state.
Is there a way to obtain the remote state configuration using the CLI without looking deep into the .terraform folder, which contents should be considered a technical detail and cannot be depended upon?

Yes, you can first do terraform workspace select <workspace name> followed by terraform state list.

That doesn't show the backend configuration, e.g. I operate on this S3 bucket

Ah sorry, I thought you want the state file. Does this help?

Thank you, that works! But are users supposed to look into .terraform/terraform.tfstate?

Well, I guess it depends. :)

I sometimes need to look up the bucket name to know whether I operate on dev, staging, or prod account

I think this is important information. I don't understand why Terraform doesn't provide CLI support for checking it :)

Unfortunately this command does not exist yet (Terraform 1.9).
There is a feature request for that and I've adapted the workaround suggested in a comment to get information about the  backend configuration.
# raw data / solution proposed
jq  < .terraform/terraform.tfstate .backend

# adapted to an S3 bucket backend
jq -r < .terraform/terraform.tfstate \
    '.backend | .type + ": " + (.config | .bucket + " -> " + .key )'

# s3: s3-my-state-bucket -> path/terraform.tfstate

